# checking whether textfield contains letters in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, contains

I am new at Javascript and I wanted to know if there is a way to check if textfield input contains anything other than numbers.

I know how to do that in Java, but Javascript is a totally different thing to me.

Answer (score 7):

Yup - just standard regex on the string:

```
var str = 'mystring 123';
if(str.match(/[^0-9]/)) { ... }
```

If you need to know how to get the string from the element:

```
var str = document.getElementById('myId').value;
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the str variable is passed in from a function and only contains number.  match is undefined.

Comment: Worked for me perfectly for the same situation.

Answer (score 5):

You can use isNaN() to check if the input is a number or not.

HTML:

```
<textarea id="inputText"></textarea>
<input type="button" onClick="checkInput();">
```

JavaScript:

```
function checkInput()
{
  var textCheck = document.getElementById("inputText").value;
  if(isNaN(textCheck))
  {
    document.write("contains letters");
  }
  else
  {
    document.write("only numbers");
  }
}
```